# Save export images from one server to another

Tags: docker

I have a number of images based on `FROM ubuntu:14.04`

When I `docker save` my images the resulting tar files are a few hundred MB.

Is there a way exclude the ubuntu image when saving my images?

I could then save the ubuntu image to a separate tar. Making my image tars smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to have a smaller image but it will still have Ubuntu on it (I don't think there's a way to save only the changes):

Create a container from your image:

```
docker run --name my_container -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Save the container only:

```
docker export my_container > my_container.tar.gz
```

Import the container as an image:

```
cat my_container.tar.gz | docker import - my_image:my_tag
```